# How to integrate GTM with Firebase analytics enabled Application which developed using Xamarin Android platform

Tags: xamarin.android, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am developing Mobile application using Xamarin Android. We have integrated Firebase portal with our application successfully. Also we are able to see all automated event and custom event on Dashboard in firebase Console.

Now my requirement is to integrate Google Tag Manager(GTM) SDK with existing Firebase SDK in my application. I tried to integrate by following some below links

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/

https://github.com/IdoTene/XamarinTagManagerAndroid

but ended up with build error **Invalid Resource file Name for GTM configuration file(GTM-XXXX.json)**.

So here is my question, How to integrate GTM SDK with Firebase SDK in Xamarin Android application.
Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [David Pearson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15659942) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67124077) saying "The iOS container should be placed at the resources folder so /resources/container [https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Google/TagManager/GettingStarted.md](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Google/TagManager/GettingStarted.md)"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you figured it out eventually, but for future reference, the problem is that the IdoTene tagmanager project is for tagmanager v4, which is pre firebase. Instead you should use the version that Xamarin maintains:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.TagManager/

Answer (score 1):

The steps are very simple. Integrate GTM containers (ios and android) as follows:

For Android -> create subfolder in `assets` folder and name it as `containers`, copy container in it (make sure it's naming starts with `GTM-xxxxxx.json`).

For iOS -> create a folder `container` in the root directory and copy GTM container json there (`GTM-xxx.json`)

Then install `Xamarin.GooglePalyServices.TagManager nuget` for Android and `Xamarin.Google.iOS.Tagmanger` for iOS.

Thats it for Android, but for iOS, there is a one more step.

Integrate following code in `AppDelegate.cs`
`Google.TagManager.TagManager.Configure();`

Then you should be good to go!! :)

Comment: Plz give source ... where did you find that information ? Thanks !